# I want to create a function that gets the value of any input passing Id

Tags: javascript, html

My question is: I want to create a function that gets the value of any input, passing the Id that i need, so I give the input `id` to the function and gets the value right away.

Right now I'm trying with this, but It doesn't work.

```js
function checkInp(input) {
  var x = document.getElementById(input).value;
  if (isNaN(x)) {
      alert("Must input numbers");
      return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="formFlMontoAprobado" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto Aprobado..." onchange="checkInp(formFlMontoAprobado)" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: Use `oninput` instead of `onchange` ... and instead of _formFlMontoAprobado_ as a parameter, use _this_. With that the paramenter _input_ in the function will be the element, so no need to use `getElementById`

Comment: I was trying to control that the user wouldn't paste a letter. 
Right now, they want to be able to copy and paste numbers in it, but I can't find the way to validate the pasting of letters.

Comment: `input type="number"` will help to start

Comment: please, explain the "it doesn't work". What happens, which error, and what is exactly the expected behavior

Comment: Right now, I'm allowing that only numbers can be inserted in the input with another function. 
The issue is that I also need to allow that the user be able to paste something in the input field (ctrl+v), but by allowing that, I'm allowing to paste letters into the field. Wich I don't want. That is why I attempted to create an "onchange" function, to verify that the pasted String does not contain letters in it.

Right now, the answers given ("oninput")do not control that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:
don't pass the id directly, pass `this`, so inside the function you'll have access to all properties of the input that invoked the function.
I made two inputs in the example below, one is using `oninput` and the other is using `onchange`, type on each of them to see the difference and choose the one that fits best for you.
Also, to help the problem of letters, i changed the type of the input to "number" instead of "text". It isn't perfect, but helps.

```js
function checkInp(input) {
  var x = input.value;
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Must input numbers");
    return false; 
  }else{
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

```html
ONINPUT: <input type="number" id="formFlMontoAprobado" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto Aprobado..." oninput="checkInp(this)" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="10" />

ONCHANGE: <input type="number" id="formFlMontoAprobado2" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto Aprobado2..." onchange="checkInp(this)" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="10" />
```